# Fitness and motion permission notification not popping up inside the app

Tags: ios, iphone, notifications, motion

[image]

My app hangs during the initial launch due to the Motion & Fitness permission notification not popping up inside the app, but instead it is showing on the iPhone's home screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please make sure that u have turned on ihealth on capabilities in Xcode